# Using Lego Mindstorms Inventions motors with arduino

Tags: arduino

The specific kit I am talking about is this one
http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/network/2000/01/31/mindstorms/

How can I integrate these motors with an arduino.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this quite easily with [this](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=17_21&products_id=81&zenid=23551fb15568be2dffcb6d248a1f116e) shield. That may be a little overkill, but if you are like me and don't know much about voltages and stuff, it is a good safe way to get some good motor drivers. I power that off of my arduino with a 9-12v wall adapter.

In order to actually connect to the motors you have a couple of options. I split one of the lego wires in the middle and wired it into the motor shield directly. Another, less destructive way would be to solder two wires to one of the metal lined lego plates and connect those wires to the board.

The motors are really just simple dc motors, so nothing special is required. Just use the example code on the instruction page for that shield.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it captncraig's way - or if you want to learn while your building I have another suggestion. What you can do instead of purchasing an already configured motor sheield you can learn how to interface a dc motor on your own. Trust me, this will come in handy later down the road. You do this with an H-Bridge.

The first thing you need to do is to figure out the specs of your motor. You would want to know the amperage and voltage it runs on and also all the stall specs. You could do this manually with a multimeter but lucky for you someone did it already.

Here are all the specs for the mindstorms motors: [your welcome ;)](http://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm)

So the next thing you have to do is find an H-Bridge that will meet those requirements. That shouldn't be too hard.

Once you have a good idea what you are doing you can put it all together. [This is a wonderful tutorial](http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Labs/DCMotorControl) that will show you how to use an H-Bridge with an arduino. It even has a sketch you can download!

Good luck and happy hacking!

Comment: http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Labs/DCMotorControl